# How to restart VScode after editing extension's config?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

VScode notifies you when you open a config of an extension:

> remember to Restart VScode

[image]

But it says nothing about how. They use capital letter for the `restart` word, so normally it should mean something if you emphasize an appellation. Is there some hidden restart button or a key shortcut?
How do I restart the IDE?

Comment: Probably save the edited files and close VScode and open it again?

Comment: This message is coming from the extension, not vscode - it's usually not required to reload vscode after changing an extension setting.

Comment: Nice question, thanks! I was just curious what an "[appellation]"(http://gobtan.sourceforge.net/tutorials/html/Text%20Editor%20Appellations.html)  is, in the context of VSCode / editors / software. Maybe it's just a fancy word for a "special name" i.e. "special command", as implied by capital letter. Thanks :)

Comment: @TheRedPea, I was just wondering that too. I wonder if the author hadn't accidentally used the wrong term, and meant "admonishment" instead.

Answer (score 495):

Execute the `workbench.action.reloadWindow` command.

There are **some ways** to do so:

1. Open the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and execute the command:

   ```
   >Reload Window
   ```
2. Define a keybinding for the command (for example <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) in `keybindings.json`:

   ```
   [
     {
       "key": "ctrl+f5",
       "command": "workbench.action.reloadWindow",
       "when": "editorTextFocus"
     }
   ]
   ```

Comment: F1 or CTRL+Shift+p or CMD+Shift+p or click `View` -> `Command Palette...`

Comment: On OSX VSCode isn't using CMD+R as a keybinding. I found it useful to set this up to reload the window. Click Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (or press CMD+K+S) search for 'reload window' and hover over and click the plus then press CMD R ENTER. Now you can reload the window simply by pressing CMD+R.

Comment: @Hunter this isn't working for me nor any other key combinations. Althought I see that CMD+R was default in my setup. Does it still works for you?

Comment: For Mac:
 Command + Shift + P, then select Reload Window from the drop down list.

Answer (score 63):

1. Open the Command Palette

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Then type:

   ```
   Reload Window
   ```

Comment: I guess that is `ctrl + shift + p` instead of `o`

Comment: For Mac, use <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd>

Answer (score 22):

You can do the following

1. Click on extensions
2. Type `Reload`
3. Then install

It will add a reload button on your right hand at the bottom of the vs code.

Comment: this worked for me.....https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natqe.reload

Comment: This is an easy-to-use tool.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this VSCode Extension called Reload

[Marketplace > **reload**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natqe.reload)

Answer (score 9):

Use **Ctrl + Shift + P** in **Windows** OR
Hit **F1** to Open Command Palette then **type `Reload Window`**

Answer (score 6):

On a Mac, Command + Shift + P , type `Reload Window` then hit enter.

Answer (score 5):

##### How to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to Restart

`File` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` -***or***-
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
(`Code` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` -***or***-
<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> on macOS).

This opens the *default Keyboard Shortcuts* window :

[image: Default Keyboard Shortcuts]

Click on the icon in the upper right corner  with tooltip
`Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` that looks like:

[image: Click this icon to open user 'keybindings.json']

This opens your `keybindings.json` on a per-user level. Paste or type :

`{"key": "ctrl+alt+r", "command": "workbench.action.reloadWindow"},`

(Make sure your keybindings are surrounded with square brackets, `[]`.)

##### Why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> ?

There are two reasons I bind *Restart VS Code* to
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> already has two other bindings:
  *File: Open Recent...* and `quickOpenNavigateNextInRecentFilesPicker`.
- It's a blink to the Microsoft legacy of
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

If you need more help, try:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-layouts

[image: If all else fails, Ctrl+Alt+Del]

Comment: I just discovered that `ctrl+alt+r` clashes with
*convert hex-color to RGBA* in the
[Hex-To-RGBA extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dakshmiglani.hex-to-rgba).
So maybe bind *Restart VSCode* to `ctrl+shift+alt+r`?
Or `ctrl+shift+alt+enter`?

Answer (score 3):

To make reload window shortcut works:

1. Press `Ctrl + Shift + p` and open command pallet
2. Type `keyboard shortcuts (JSON)` and press enter
3. On the `keybindings.json` file:

> - On the `key` field pass the shortcut
> - On the `command` field pass workbench.action.reloadWindow
> - On `when` field pass a empty string to this shortcut work without an specific condition

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+f5",
        "command": "workbench.action.reloadWindow",
        "when": ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Method1

VIEW->COMMAND PALETTE->RELOAD WINDOW

[image]

### Method2

<kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
Then Type: ***Reload window*** (Method1 same but using shortcut)

### [image]
Method3

<kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

NB:if Method3 did'nt work try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/71046140/7706354

Comment: For method 3 to work, you need to remove When "is Development" condition. The attached link shows how you can do it (right mouse click, change when expression).

Answer (score 1):

Cmd+Shift+P Developer: Restart Extension Host

[image: Command Palette Developer Restart Extension Host]

It is easier now, and maybe more granular than "restart window".

Answer (score 1):

For a more comprehensive restart, use `File → Exit`.

Indeed, Google search seems to insist that this post also answers: How to restart VSCode so that changes to `$path` are reflected? Unfortunately, the suggested `reloadWindow` function does *not* update changes to `$path`.

The answer is to use the menu item `File → Exit` — a *hot exit*. Then restart VScode.