# Why does Prettier not format code in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, nuxt.js, prettier

In my Nuxt application where ESlint and Prettier are installed and enabled, I switched to Visual Studio Code.

When I open a **.vue** file and press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  and choose **Format Document**, my file does not get [formatted](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) at all.

My  **.prettierrc** [settings](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html):

```
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

I have so many source code lines, so I cannot format them manually. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems that prettier by default has [prettier.disableLanguages](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode#user-content-prettier.disablelanguages-(default%3A-%5B%22vue%22%5D)) set to `["vue"]`

Comment: I'd add to `.prettierrc` line `"disableLanguages": []`. Docs says that this change requires restart

Comment: There's also [issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/590) for v1.27.2 with note that the same config worked for v.1.23

Comment: Indeed, I have VSCode 1.27.2

Comment: Upvoted b/c just pressing `CMD`+ `Shift` + `P` then **Format Document**, then choosing Prettier as my default formatter helped me :D

Comment: If nothing works for you, be sure to check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273353/4298115

Comment: For me, it was not working even after making all the configuration setting changes. Then, I realized I was trying to format a code fragment `var x = "test";` written in HTML file when I should have written it in a `*.JS` file. When I wrote the JS code into a JS file it got formatted to `var x = 'test'`.

Comment: Try to **disable prettier** –> **reload vscode** -> **enable prettier**

Comment: Note that [Prettier can not format python files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNqVs.png).

Comment: @Shub Python is quite opinionated in terms of formatting by default. You can always use this if you really need formatting: https://github.com/psf/black

Answer (score 1297):

1. Select `File -> Preferences -> Settings` (`Ctrl` + `comma`) and search form `formatter`
2. Set Prettiers as Default formatter.
   [image]

If above does not work:

`ctrl+shift+p > Format Document With... > Configure Default Formatter... > Prettier - Code formatter`

This also work with `ctrl+shift+I`

Comment: I did configure Prettier as std formatter in settings but it just would not work. This worked. Made my day!

Comment: Same here, but I had to de-select my default formatter and then perform the action you mention again for this to work.

Comment: Not sure where to find `Configure Default Formatter` but I used File->Settings->Text Editor->Default Formatter

Comment: When I select the default formatter as Prettier, it formats that file but after that it does not work on save. I have my save option checked but still. I had to select the default formatter again and again. Any Solution

Comment: @HimanshuTariyal This should work for you, but feel free to check out my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273353/4298115

Comment: Is this some kind of issue in vscode? It worked for me as well

Comment: What about making prettier AND eslint make changes to the code?

Comment: @jrypkahauer this is basically [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585). ☺️

Comment: My VSCode is suddenly adding a blank line at the end of file when I save. I have disabled all options to add a new line. I even uninstalled the `Prettier` extension. But it still keeps adding a new blank line at the end of file when I press `ctrl + s`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: This works, however , only after a recent change in that document. if I write something , don't format yet and switch to another file and edit , then it will not format either of the files . in such case there is an option to create a nice keybind to force it. type Format Document (Forced) in command palette and configure keybindings , then press on the pen to edit a new key binding .

Comment: The prettier wasn't showing up even after being installed. Reinstalled and reloaded and it started working. thanks

Comment: When I did this I found that the (also modified elsewhere) was present (as in the picture). I hovered over it and it told me it was being modified by the workspace. I followed the link and found the workspace had a rule "format on save" unchecked. I checked that as well and now it formats on save.

Comment: On a Mac the first step would be `Code > Preferences > Settings`

Answer (score 539):

If doing what @Simin Maleki mentioned does not solve it for you, there is a chance that your default formatter is not set:

```
File > Preferences > Settings > Search for "default formatter"
```

Make sure your `Editor: Default Formatter` field is not `null` but rather `Prettier - Code formatter (esbenp.prettier-vscode)` and that all the languages below are ticked. This fixed my issue.

#### STEP BY STEP WALKTHROUGH

[image: Steps to enable default formatter]

**Also make sure that your format on save is enabled:**

[image: Format on save check]

Comment: Randomly my vscode stop working with prettier after months of working correctly, don't know why this fixes it :pray:

Comment: @ncubica Exact same thing happened to me and I was very confused since I did nothing to cause the issue. Took a bit of digging but finally found this and had to share. Glad it works for you :)

Comment: I did this and also tried the solution from @miha to no avail. Finally uninstalled/reinstalled and it worked

Comment: A couple gotchas that were required for this to work: 

1. remote needs to be configured for prettier if you're using those features, and 
2. I had to restart vscode in order for this to work.

Comment: I needed to first install the [Prettier VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

Comment: While my last screen looks nothing like yours (the latest VS Code has no formatter options), the tip to use the search is what eventually found the default formatter setting for me.

Comment: it worked for me with latest vscode. thanks

Answer (score 154):

Sometimes, Prettier stops working when there are syntactic errors in the code. You can view the errors by clicking on the **x** button on the bottom right corner beside **Prettier**.

[image: A screenshot of the bottom right corner of the VS Code window, capturing the status bar in this region. One option is "Prettier," which has an X next to it indicating that errors are present.]

Comment: Sometimes Prettier won't show at the bottom, but another extension (eg. ESLint) will, and if you click on it there's a drop-down to pick other tools ... including Prettier.  Pick it to see Prettier's log (and after that Prettier should show in the tray).

Comment: I do not see `prettier` at the bottom right. I have `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",` and installed the ext. Want powershell format.

Comment: not only for syntactic errors but other errors with your configuration (for example, wrong .prettierrc path) will appear here too

Comment: In my case, I had killed a bunch of VSCode plugin from Activity Monitor. `CMD+ Shift + P > Developer: Reload Window` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 116):

Prettier could also format your files on save.

However, installing and enabling does not result in working.

You have to check "format on Save" in VSCode: *Setting >> User >> Text Editor >> Formatting*

[image]

Comment: also `alt (command) + shift + f` is for formatting without save.

Comment: Note that, in addition to Format On Save being enabled, you also often have to have a default formatter specified.

Comment: Following every solution from the top, it worked at this point : ) , thanks  a lot

Comment: Using `alt (command) + shift + f` helped me. A pop up came up to select default formatter since there were multiple present.

Comment: Also alt + shift + f, give me an easy way to choice default Formatter

Comment: Setting a default formatter and doing this worked for me, thanks! Weird that this isn't true on default.

Comment: @yaya I think that's `OPTION` instead of `COMMAND` on Mac. So `OPTION+SHIFT+F`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Somehow on Linux Kubuntu it was off

Answer (score 80):

You only have to configure your **Default Formatter** and check the checkbox in **Format On Save** in the settings, after installing prettier to make it work. Don't mess with other configuration files.

#### 1 - Select Default Formatter

1. Open `Files -> Preferences -> Settings` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> in Windows).
2. Search for `Editor: Default Formatter`
3. Select your **default formatter** as `Prettier - Code Formatter`;

See the image below;

[image: Default Formatter Capture]

#### 2 - Format On Save

1. Open `Files -> Preferences -> Settings` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> in Windows).
2. Search for `Editor: Format on Save`
3. Click the check box under `Format On Save`;

See the image below;

[image: Format On Save Capture]

Comment: I did all this and still was not working. I have a mono repo. After removing .prettierrc and .eslintrc file from my sub project and only keeping my main mono repo file, it started to work.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 62):

disable and enable `prettier` extension solves my problem

Comment: If all the other configs are right, this will do the trick.

Comment: Can't believe this was it... Was trying to fix this for almost an HOUR. Had vs extensions installed, npm packages installed, settings.json setup, eslintrc was good to go, tried toggling settings, going in settings panel, everything... I'm just amazed this was it, since I tried "turning it off and on again" in every other regard and the settings seemed to be applied instantly...

Comment: It looks like my issue was caused by upgrading my version of node. Doing this fixed the problem.

Comment: Using `Developer: Reload Window` from the command palette worked for me too.

Comment: This worked for me when I'm configuring formatting for Solidity files, and I spent 2 weeks trying to make it work again only to find up a simple "have you tried turning it off and on" would have worked. :/

Answer (score 52):

I am not using Vue, but had the same problem.

I already had the settings

- `Editor: default formatter` to prettier
- `Editor: Format on Save` to `true`
- I already had `.eslintrc.js` and `.prettierrc` files
  But nothing worked.

The solution to my problem was that I had all set properly, except I needed to:

- `Command` + `Shift` + `p`
- type `format document with`
- select `Configure Default Formatter...`
- select `Prettier` as default.

I don't know why the `Editor: Format on Save` set to `true` was not enough.
I needed to select default formatter using the above steps so it worked.

[image]

Comment: If you do have an ESlint config already, you should probably use Prettier via ESlint. Here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585) on how to achieve such thing.

Answer (score 50):

can you try to add this section to your VS Code settings.json file?

```
"[javascript]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
},
```

Comment: That was also my case.
The default formatter was set to the correct one by formatting on save was disabled.

Comment: That's my case!! Thanks, It didn't work because formatOnSave was set to false in json

Answer (score 30):

These three steps may solve your problem:

[image: Prettier Doesn't format code]

1 - Go to settings, then search for `auto format`

2 - Select `Text Editor`

3 - Select `esbenp.prettier-vscode` as your Default Formatter.

> Simply said, go to Settings > User tab > Text Editor > Editor: Default Formatter and change it to prettier.

Answer (score 20):

On Windows:

We can open the below file using:

```
Start > Run
```

File Path:

```
%AppData%\Code\User\settings.json
```

Change
From:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
},
```

To:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

Note:

- If the above is not present, add it instead of changing.
- You should already have installed the "Prettier - code formatter" to see the effect of the above change - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: @BillalBegueradj True, accepted didn't work for me, and I wasted about 1 hour, so posted this one. Maybe this is a more recent issue that we face in 2020.

Comment: Your solution is the “non graphical” approach to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273353/4298115

Comment: @lbragile I could not do it using GUI, hence above solution. Especially, this is better way when we have several formatters for various languages, there is no time to waste when we can copy-paste one line by opening one file.

Comment: How to add in macos?

Comment: @MalithKuruppu This also works on macOS. You just need to press cmd+p and select "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" to get to the `settings.json` file.

Answer (score 18):

you can still have issues in spite of all these settings. In this case, as pointed out in an earlier answer, then it would be a good point to check the prettier notification at bottom status bar in VSCode.

[image]

When clicking on that status, the output panel should report the issue in the HTML file. For me, the issue was I had a div inside a p tag which I assume prettier/VSCode conventions are against. When I removed it (and combined with all the settings above, namely **default formatter** and **format on save**) I got prettier working.

.prettierrc is not required unless you want to override VSCode settings

Answer (score 15):

For me the problem was with HTML files where formatting stopped working one day. I had **Format On Save** configured, which worked in all files except HTML.

I then realized that I experimentally set **Format On Save Mode** to `modification` instead of `file` and forgot about it. This had an effect of not formatting anything in HTML files, surprisingly not even my changes. Setting it back to `file` solved the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This is not a problem with Prettier itself, but `prettier-vscode`, the VSCode extension. According to [its documentation](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettierdisablelanguages-default-vue), Vue formatting is disabled by default:

> **prettier.disableLanguages (default: ["vue"])**
>
> A list of languages IDs to disable this extension on. Restart required. *Note: Disabling a language enabled in a parent folder will prevent formatting instead of letting any other formatter to run*

In this case, to enable you should set `"prettier.disableLanguages": []`. And since this is an extension configuration, you should do it in VSCode settings file, not `.prettierrc`.

Comment: This setting has been removed.

Comment: Yep, OP should update or remove it or downvotes will flow... :p

Answer (score 13):

in my case it was being hijacked by typescript formatter.

it was driving me crazy because it kept re-formatting my spaces!

to fix i did `cmd+.` (settings) type -> "default formatter"

and unchecked typescript

[image]

Comment: Legend! Thanks so much, this has been such a pain for me!

Answer (score 12):

1 .Use the other extension prettier was not working for me i just use the other VSCODE extension named `PrettierNow` i think this will help, done for me.[Checkout the extension here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=remimarsal.prettier-now)

2 .From Latest Updates of prettier you need to add `.prettierrc` file in your root of the projects if you want to stick with prettier.
An example of `.prettierrc` is this-

```
{
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi": false
}
```

Answer (score 11):

## How to format your code through VScode's ESlint plugin

Alright, rather than giving a guide on how to use [VScode's Prettier extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), I'd rather explain how to rely on ESlint and have both worlds: checking that your code is correct (ESlint), then formatting it (Prettier).

### What are the advantages of this?

- not forcing your **entire team** to use VScode with the Prettier extension, maybe some prefer Vim, IntelliJ's Webstorm, Emacs etc... A tool-agnostic solution is IMO always better.
- I think that linting your code is more important that formatting it, but if you have both extensions working at the same time, you may have conflicts between the formatting and the linting.
- your hardware will struggle less, if you have less extensions running (mainly because it can stop the conflicts)
- using an ESlint + Prettier combo will strip the need to have a specific personal configuration aside of the codebase (untracked). You'll also benefit from having Vue/Nuxt specific ESlint rules and a simpler/more universal configuration.
- an ESlint configuration can be configured to be run before a commit, in a CI/CD or anywhere really.

### How to achieve this kind of setup?

Let's start first by installing the [ESlint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) and only it, **DO NOT** install the Prettier one.

[image]

#### Not installed [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) yet?

I do heavily recommend it for Vue2 apps (what Nuxt is running as of today), you can find it below. It will allow to quickly and simply ESlint (+ Prettier) any `.vue` files.

---

When it's done, access the `Command Palette` with either `ctrl + shift + p` (Windows/Linux) or `cmd + shift + p` (Mac) and type `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)`

[image]

There, you should have something like this

```json
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Dark", // example of some of your own configuration

  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
  },
  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions": [
      ".html",
      ".js",
      ".vue",
      ".jsx",
    ]
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact",
    "html",
    "vue",
  ],
}
```

### How to try that your configuration is now working?

To see if my solution is working, please download this [Github repo](https://github.com/kissu/so-eslint-prettier-test), get the latest stable Node version (eg: 14) and run `yarn` to have it working. Otherwise, simply open VScode.
This repo can also be used to double-check that yours is properly configured by inspecting my files there!

Then, you could access any `.js` or `.vue` file and see the problems there (Command Palette: `Problems: Focus on Problems View`). `nuxt.config.js` and `/pages/index.vue` are good examples, here is the `index.vue` file.

[image]

You can see that we do have several things that can be fixed by Prettier but that we do also have an [`eslint(vue/require-v-for-key)`](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/require-v-for-key.md) error. The solution is available as a comment just below btw.

PS: if you want to have inline ESlint warnings/errors as in the screenshot, you can install [Error Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens), it's a super amazing extension if you want to get rid of errors.

**Save this file** and you should saw that every auto-fixable things are done for you. Usually it's mainly Prettier issues but it can also sometimes be ESlint too. Since we do have the ESlint rules from Nuxt, you'll get some nice good practices out of the box too!

Tada, it's working! If it's not, read the section at the end of my answer.

### If you want to create a brand new project

You can run `npx create-nuxt-app my-super-awesome-project` and select few things there, the most important being `Linting tools: Eslint + Prettier` of course (hit space to opt-in for one of them).

[image]

**Warning**: as of today, there is an additional step to do to have ESlint + Prettier working properly as shown in this [Github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9563#issue-946135176). The fix should be released pretty soon, then the configuration below will not be needed anymore!

To fix this, run `yarn add -D eslint-plugin-prettier` and double check that your `.eslintrc.js` file is a follows

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    requireConfigFile: false
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended', // this line was updated
    'prettier'
  ],
  plugins: [
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {}
}
```

Then, you can have it working totally fine as above. Save the file and it should run ESlint then Prettier one after the other!

---

#### If you still have some issues

- try to use the `Command Palette` again and `ESLINT: restart ESLint Server` or even `Developer: Reload Window`
- feel free to leave a comment or [contact me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816585/kissu?tab=profile) if you need some help

Answer (score 11):

Simply **Right click** anywhere in the area where code formatting isn't working as expected

and Select **Format Document With..**. from the context menu.

[image]

and then click on **Configure Defulte Formatter...**

[image]

and then click on **Prettier** in this list.
[image]

This should resolve the issue after doing some changes on file and save that.

Comment: it configures it but still it's not done automatically on save after the above steps

Answer (score 9):

**If Prettier formats all other files except HTML files automatically on save:**

Press `Cmd + P` or `Ctrl + P` to open the command palette and type the following text in it:

```
> open settings
```

Click on `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` from the suggestion dropdown.
Inside the `settings.json` file, Check if `"[html]"` key exists. If the key exists and its value indicates using another formatting extension installed in Visual Studio Code, you should reset it back to use **Prettier**.

```
"[html]": {
    "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

For an instance, sometimes, the value of `"[html]"` key could be `"remimarsal.prettier-now"` when you would have Prettier Now extension installed.

If you don't have any other formatting extension installed other than Prettier, you can also remove the `"[html]"` key altogether from `settings.json` file.

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me (my default formatter was already set to Prettier)

1. Change default formatter to `default`
2. Restart vscode
3. Change default formatter back to `Prettier`.

Comment: To [restart vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002990/9868383) Open the command palette `(Ctrl + Shift + P)` and execute the command: `Reload Window`, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Enabling **"format on Save" in VSCode: Setting >> User >> Text Editor >> Formatting** worked for me!

[image: Print]

Answer (score 7):

Go to **Manage**(located on left-bottom corner) -> **Settings** -> **Users** tab -> **Text-Editor** -> **Formatting** -> **check the format on save**

if not working then close and again open your vscode editor

Answer (score 5):

Recently I got the same problem, that Prettier does not format code automatically on saving. Checking Prettier, I saw an error: Invalid `"arrowParens"` value. Expected "always" or "avoid", but received `true`.

The error message was seen when I clicked this:
[image]

It turned out that I have Prettier Now installed also. This has a boolean value in my config file. After uninstalling Prettier Now, everything works fine.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it turned out I had configured prettier to use a configuration file that didn't exist (see screnshot below). That was hard to find since there wasn't any error message but prettier just didn't work. Maybe this helps somebody, too.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

If none of the other answers work, check that a conflicting prettier config `.prettierrc` does not exist in your working directory or check for `.prettierignore` to be sure the files/folders are not being ignored.

Comment: Yep for me it was an older path... So it doesn't works silently.

Answer (score 4):

Check if there is a .vscode/settings.json file in your project directory (workspace). In my case someone had checked in this file:

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

Solution: Delete the file (delete it from source control too) and add `.vscode/` to .gitignore (if you're using git).

Answer (score 4):

In some cases where prettier is provided as a dependency, you might need to install it before prettier vscode recognizes it using one of the following commands, depending on the package manager you are using
`npm i`  or  `yarn`

Answer (score 4):

From the menu navigate through: `view -> Command Palette`
Form the command palette search for `Format Document` and then select Prettier as your format engine.

I had prettier already working on another project, but for the new one I had do it through this way to enable it again for the new project.

Answer (score 4):

Check your `package.json` file for a property of `prettier` as this will take precedence.

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "scripts": { ... },

  "prettier": {},

  "dependencies": { ... },
  "devDependencies": { ... },
}
```

Delete this property and the `.prettierrc` file will be used.

The order of precedence is stated in the [prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

Answer (score 3):

Some times with auto plugins update Required files used by Prettier might go missing .

Check this path if files are present here or folder is empty

C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-2.2.2\out

If missing uninstall and reinstall prettier

Comment: > "If missing uninstall and reinstall prettier" is what did it for me. I had all the settings right, and running prettier from an NPM script even worked right, but formatting on save didn't until I uninstalled and reinstalled.

Answer (score 3):

I Rolling back prettier to 1.7.3 and fixed it

Answer (score 3):

For me - it was to do with ESlint which also works with Prettier. Eslint wasn't working (a local installation vs global installation conflict) which broke Prettier.

Comment: How to resolved this.
I am having an issue where Eslint is asking for a new line when press enter and save
it gets back to the same position and error starts appearing again.

Comment: If you do have an ESlint config already, you should probably use Prettier via ESlint. Here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585) on how to achieve such thing.

Answer (score 3):

**The only thing I needed to do was update my packages with a simple**

```
npm install
```

I tried everything on here and it was still not working. Just seemed like it does not exist. Prettier was also added as a dependency in the project. It turned out that someone else had added or updated any package which caused my prettier to stop working.

Hoping it saves someone the headache it caused me.

Comment: `npm install` installs the dependecies specified in your `package.json` + their version ranges. It doesn't update anything per-se. Important difference IMO.

Comment: Yes @kissu you are right. The important things here is that because of the difference prettier stopped working. And after running it, prettier was able to work again. So may be for someone else who is also overlooking this it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to do the following:

1. Install prettier from the command line(`npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier prettier-plugin-custom`)
2. Reload VSCode

and voilà, everything started working.

**TIP:**
To make sure the installation is good I checked for the version:

```
npx prettier --version
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had `prettier` installed globally already, but it didn't work. If I had to guess, it might have been a WSL issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check for requirePragma in .prettierrc, it says you need to add a top level comment for that file to be formatted

remove that rule and it should work

Answer (score 2):

For me helped disabled this option in VS Code settings (then prettier use default config):

> Prettier: Require Config

Answer (score 2):

I am working in WSL (will also work for people having the problem only in cutom workspaces) and I tried EVERY fix possible until I found this tab on vscode settings:
[image]

Select the tab regarding your problem and change all the settings you want again and change the setting "Files: Auto Save" to either "onFocusChange" or "onWindowChange".

Answer (score 2):

In my case I simply just needed to check the `Format On Save` checkbox in the formatting settings. Press `shift+cmd+p` to bring up the search and then press `Preferences: Open User Settings`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to enable "editor.defaultFormatter" in the settings of the VSCode. In my case it was null and hence even the "editor.formatOnSave" was also not seeming to solve the issue.

Comment: What does this add to the other 4 answers that mention the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to enable "Format On Save" and set the "Auto Save Delay" to 0. It worked, so I guess you could try this too.

Edit: You can see them through these steps.

> 1. `Manage`(The gear Icon bottom left)

> 2. `Settings`(Inside the manage dropdown list)

> 3. Search for `Format On Save` and enable it(check the box)

> 4. Scroll down and look for `Auto Save Delay` and set it to `0`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few syntaxes that prettier is not able to parse. `??` is one of them. After removing the symbol my prettier worked like a charm. You should take a look at the output of the Prettier extension in vscode. That should point out the line and the syntax which is causing problems for prettier to format properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set all things which you can do in Setting and Prettier is not working. Try to install it through this command line.
`npm install --save-dev prettier`

Comment: Despite `npx prettier --version` working, I wasn't getting any auto-formatting until I ran the `install` command in this answer. (I used `yarn`, but the result is the same.)

Answer (score 1):

here my prettier config working on vue.js files, typescript files and json files.

```
arrowParens: 'always'
bracketSpacing: true
endOfLine: 'crlf'
htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: 'css'
insertPragma: false
jsxBracketSameLine: false
jsxSingleQuote: true
overrides:
- files: '*.json'
  options:
    semi: true
    parser: 'json'
parser: 'babel'
printWidth: 120
proseWrap: 'preserve'
quoteProps: 'truepreserve'
requirePragma: false
semi: false
singleQuote: true
tabWidth: 8
trailingComma: 'es5'
useTabs: true
vueIndentScriptAndStyle:
```

Do not forget to update your vscode settings

```
{
"extensions.ignoreRecommendations": false,
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
"[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
},
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
},
"vetur.format.options.useTabs": true}
```

that's all folk's !

Comment: `"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},`
Worked perfectly for me! Otherwise everything else was set fine but still prettier was not working on save.

Answer (score 1):

For my case i was using a windows machine and it turned out the file system had been corrupted thus prettier raised an error because it could not be able to open the config file due to file system corruption.

TO resolve it I run `chkdsk /f h:` on the terminal where h is the file partition.

This resolved the file corruption and prettier is now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem when I moved from Ubuntu to Windows 10.

The problem was with shortcuts 'ctrl + shirt + i', which was default on Ubuntu but was not in Win10.

Go to file -> preferences -> keyboard shortcuts.

Then write prettier and find 'Format Document (Forced)'.
Click on pencil on left and write keyboard shortcut, press Enter.

If it is not possible because there is already command written to that shortcut, find it and change it to something else. Then it will be possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Default formatter with modified elsewhere tag]

For those looking to get this working with Prisma and other overriding extensions or project settings (like in the image above), use the following:

```js
// Inside .vscode/settings.json
{
  // other extensions
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[prisma]": { // replace this with the language that is overriding 
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Prisma.prisma" // Replace this with the extension/formatter you want for that language
  },
  // rest of .vscode/settings.json
}
```

You shouldn't override project settings by forcing your editor settings as some other answers would suggest. This will just annoy your team and or whoever manages the repository you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I got rid of parser: json in the .pretterrc file.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event that none of the above solutions work for you (like me), I had to set the default formatter to null in settings, then hit CTRL + SHIFT + P and search for "format document" (the default format document binding +R didn't work for me) then I was prompted to select a default formatter in a popup and after selecting prettier it formatted the document and also formats on saving now

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this. I tried all the solutions being extolled, none worked. Then I set my formatter to Null, closed/reopened VS Code, formatted a document and Prettier magically started working since it detected my .prettierrc file. Previously it kept trying to use the VS Code settings even though I told it to user Prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, since its not already here...

I was trying to format a minified `.js` file in my `node_modules` folder so I could understand the code better and Prettier kept returning:

```
["INFO" - 7:13:19 PM] File is ignored, skipping.
```

In this case, you can force-format by opening the Command Palette `Ctrl+Shift+P` and then selecting `Format Document (Forced)` to have it format a file that would normally be ignored.

[image: Forced]

Answer (score 0):

I've tried done all stuff but my codebase is not getting formatted.
Then I checked my `.prettierignore` & some other developer just wrote `/src` there.

I removed it & everything is working fine now

Answer (score -4):

I tried every single solution in this thread, and I just realized that my only issue was my **Visual Studio color theme**. That simple!

**Before**:
[image]

**After**:
[image]

Comment: The emojis tho!