# there is no selection formatter for 'cpp'-files installed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use ctrl+K ctrl+F in vscode to auto align my .cpp codes, but it doesn't work with hint "there is no selection formatter for 'cpp'-files installed", however, when I copy the code to Formatting part of Interactive Playground in vscode, it works. why? that's strange?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71282125/1919793

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
shift+alt+f
```

If it does not work Install Prettier format extension and [set default formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-prettier-does-not-format-code-in-vscode)
If still not work use Clang Formatter

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a beautifier extension that supports cpp. 
The best I've found is this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp 
Ctrl-Shift-X brings you to extensions, search for "beautify c++" and select "C/C++ 0.20.1" from the result list.