# C/C++ Extension Formatter Appears Not to Work

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I run `Ctrl-Shift-I`, I get the pop-up "There is no formatter for 'cpp' files installed." However, I do have the Microsoft C/C++ extension installed. Why might I be getting this error message?

To clarify, I am aware of other third-party formatters (e.g., the Clang-Format package) but ideally I would like to get the formatter in the C/C++ extension working.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. For me, it was caused by the

```
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "disabled",
```

line in the settings json.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file is saved and is not an "untitled" raw file.

This is, unfortunately, not a bug but an expected [behavior of the extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8761).

> Our extension requires that the file be saved first and not be an "Untitled" document.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting it in your `settings.json`, it may have an incorrect configuration.

```json
"[c]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen and tried:

- setting editor.defaultFormatter to various extensions like ms-vscode cpptools and clang-format
- Disabling all installed extensions, restarting VS Code, and reenabling
- Installing other extensions and tools
- Installing the extensions to WSL as well
- Updating VS Code to the latest version

But what fixed it for me was **opening the file from the VS Code Explorer pane instead of dragging the file into VS Code from Windows File Explorer**. Even though it is part of the workspace, it seems to matter.

The key difference I was seeing is that until opening from within VS Code, I didn't have the option to [F1] -> "Format Document With..." but only had the option to "Format Document".

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way to unistall and install vs code. And install c/c++ exetension from the Microsoft.

Comment: That is neither a simple not desirable solution to the problem. Simply uninstalling and reinstalling software might fix a problem, but is equally likely to solve nothing. But it is also likely to cause unnecessary additional work, cause data loss, or potentially mask another problem that will return later.