# potentially fixable with the `--fix` option

Tags: vue.js, eslint, nuxt.js

I am creating a app with nuxt.js but everytime I launch the app, gives me the error of eslint and saying "potentially fixable with the `--fix` option."

I did the command `npm run lint -- --fix` and it works but then If I do another change in any vue file it comes again the same error and I have to do it again

Any idea of how to fix that?

Comment: Is your editor formatting on save? Is it doing it the same way ESLint enforces?

Comment: No it's not. Should it be @jonrsharpe?

Comment: I asked two questions, which were you answering? If you're asking whether your editor should be applying the same formatting that your linter expects: yes, otherwise you *keep having to reformat it*.

Comment: Yeah you right. My answer would fit both of your questions. Yes it was for the first one. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Was looking for this: `npm run lint -- --fix` - thank you!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the below configuration into nuxt config file:

```js
build: {
  extend(config, ctx) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      options: {
        fix: true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Important part is:

```js
options: {
  fix: true
}
```

Comment: Can you give a line by line explanation for lines 2 to 5? MIght be valuable for posterity

Comment: @ledawg this is nowadays not a needed solution anymore.

Comment: Funny I keep running into these issues in 2021 then...

Answer (score 9):

Extend the build in the `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
build: {
  extend(config, ctx) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      enforce: "pre",
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: "eslint-loader",
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      options: {
        fix: true
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If anyone facing this issue when working with Cloud Functions try this. Find `package.json` file inside `functions` folder, replace

```
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
```

with

```
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts . --fix",
```

Then run the command again:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

It should fix all issues which fixable. If any error left (sometimes 1 or 2 still left) find that one and edit manually and voila it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using VScode, I recommend doing a full ESlint configuration in your project as I've [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585).

Having this [ESlint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) and that in your `settings.json` (accessible via Command Palette)

```json
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true, // this one will fix it on save for you
  },
  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions": [
      ".html",
      ".js",
      ".vue",
      ".jsx",
    ]
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact",
    "html",
    "vue",
  ],
}
```

On top of a simple `.eslintrc.js` file like this

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    requireConfigFile: false,
  },
  extends: ['@nuxtjs']
}
```

Followed by this in the settings UI, should give you a great DX.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this error, *potentionally fixable with the '--fix' option.*, unfortunately `npm run lint -- --fix` didn't do anything. Running `npm run format` fixed the errors.

- `lint` is for flagging errors
- `format` is for fixing errors

```json
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint \"**/*.{js,mjs}\" && prettier --check --loglevel warn \"**/*.{js,mjs,json}\" && stylelint \"**/*.scss\"",
    "format": "eslint \"**/*.{js,mjs}\" --fix && prettier --write --loglevel warn \"**/*.{js,mjs,json}\" && stylelint \"**/*.scss\" --fix",
}
```

Comment: Got `npm ERR! Missing script: "format"`
What is your script for `format`?

Answer (score 1):

I am also face the same problem.

Then I got a solution

**use this command :-> npm run lint:js -- --fix**

Hope your problem will be solved