# Why is VS Code Prettier extension not working?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, prettier

I've recently installed the Prettier VS Code extension on my work computer, because I love how it makes my code look on my personal computer. For some reason, though I've uninstalled the extension, reinstalled it, and restarted VS Code, Prettier isn't working. All the answers to this problem I come across seem to attribute this to problems working with ESLint, but I don't have that installed. 
Here are the extensions I do have installed:
- Ayu
- Colorize
- Debugger for Java
- Java Dependency Viewer
- Java Extension Pack
- Java Test Runner 
- jshint
- Language support for Java
- Maven for Java
- Prettier
- Python
- Simple React Snippets
- SQL server
- Visual Studio IntelliCode - Preview
Any guesses what's going on?

Comment: What do you mean specifically with "it does not work"? Prettier does not do anything by default. Only if you select "Format document" in the command pallet - or have FormatOnSave" activated, will it do anything

Comment: @PatrickHollweck I selected Format Document in the command pallet and I saw a few changes. But, it didn't change tabs to two spaces, double to single quotes, etc. I'm not sure where to activate FormatOnSave - I don't see it as an option under the Prettier settings.

Comment: @Andy J have you been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

For me setting `default formatter` to `esbenp.prettier-vscode` fixed the issue.

Go to setting by entering `cmd` + `,` and search for "default formatter". If it's null change it to `esbenp.prettier-vscode`. Don't forget to change it on both "Workspace" and "User".

Also credits to: @lbragile https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273353/8779275

Comment: Surprised this hasn't been marked as the answer.