# Prettier doesn't work on VScode after update

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I recently updated VSCode and Prettier is not working anymore on my JS files. Before whenever I saved my JS files, Prettier would add the semicolons for me. Now when I save, no semicolons are added. I have the plugin enabled and checked the settings to make sure I have the semicolon insertions enabled. What could be causing this error?

[image: default settings]

[image: enabled settings]

[image: semicolons enabled]

Comment: Same here, prettier isn't working anymore where it still worked two days ago (didn't do an update). I've reinstalled vscode but that didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one worked for me:

1. Select `View` -> `Command Palette` (or type `CMD` + `shift`+ `P`)
2. Type: `Format Document`
3. Choose Prettier as your default formatter

Original answer: [Why Prettier does not format code in VSCODE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-prettier-does-not-format-code-in-vscode)