# Pretier extension not working despite setting as default formatter

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

After recently updating my VS Code, my prettier stopped working.
The error says:

Extension 'Prettier - Code Formatter' cannot format (insert path here).

What I've tried to fix this issue,

1. Setting the default formatter from 'null' to 'esbenp.prettier-vscode'
2. Manually setting prettier as default formatter in settings.json
   [image]

3. Install/Uninstall the prettier extension
4. Install/Uninstall VS Code itself and wiping out all extensions installed

All of this doesn't work at all and I'm out of ideas on how to fix this issue.

Prettier Version: 5.8.0
VS Code Version: 1.51.5

Comment: this is probably because you have prettier disabled for .js files. Does your prettier work on html and css?

Comment: You might have an empty .prettierrc in your project.

Comment: @SamyakJain It doesn't work on html and css too

Comment: @Sandsten How can i check or where to find .prettierrc ???

Comment: If you have a .prettierrc file under the root directory of your project it will override the settings.json file. If there's no .prettierrc file, then what you have in settings.js should be applied.

Comment: Does it say prettier in the bottom hand right corner of VSCode when you have a .js file open?

Comment: @Sandsten No, the prettier label doesn't show up anymore. I also don't have a .prettierrc file on my project directory

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58669550/5903504

Comment: @Sandsten yes I already did.

Answer (score 0):

From [Sandstens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5903504/sandsten) answer, I got a solution working for myself. Just create a .prettierrc file in the root of your directory, and go to https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html, copy the json config on the page, I'll paste it here for convenience:

```
{
 "trailingComma": "es5",
 "tabWidth": 4,
 "semi": false,
 "singleQuote": true
}
```

Then navigate to the file in your project and try seeing if it'll format upon save

Answer (score 0):

After having tried multiple methods (including all the ones you have [maria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10353761/maria)) I've come across a fix that works, at least for me.

### Steps

1. Navigate to the root of your project
2. Right click on the `.prettierrc` file

   - If you don't have this file, check out [JORDANO's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66163313/16292553) answer
3. Select 'Copy Path'
4. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (Windows)

   - Alternatively, go to File/Code > Preferences > Settings
5. Search settings for `prettier.configPath`
6. Finally, paste the path you copied on step 3

I came across this fix as I was scrolling through Prettier's settings and noticed the 'Prettier: Config Path' box was empty. Hopefully this helps anybody else that is having this problem. Make sure to try all the other methods [maria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10353761/maria) tried if my fix doesn't work for you!