# Prettier not working on my vscode.I've installed it on my vscode and do all the important settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, prettier

I've installed prettier on my vscode and do all the settings for that. But it is still not working.
Settings I've applied: default formatter prettier, format on save. But it still not working. Please help me.!!

Comment: **Off topic to this question**  Hi, wanted to give some feedback on your CV, but you closed the question. Generally, it's not a bad CV, all the info is there.  Some points:   1) top priority: check spelling. "Objecives" really jumped out  similar "I've create" (created) 2) only include a pic if it's standard in your area (in UK it's not) 3) well done for keeping to a single page (as recommended)

Comment: 4) you may not be getting offers as you state you're still in full time education (2018-continue) with no clear end-date.  It's unlikely someone would ask you to work for them if it meant aborting your studies.  Add an end date of when you think your studies will end.  5) too many "etc."  6) just "created many" not "sooooo many" 7) use "self study" rather than "online resources" (I'm not an expert on this, but that's would I would prefer to see as the interviewer)  7) wording in objectives sounds a bit creepy, but I don't have a better suggestion

Comment: Up vote these comments when you've read them and I'll delete them

Answer (score 3):

1. press `shift + alt + f` together
2. if its open select folder then choose the folder you want for prettier
3. if gives you 2 options prettier or any other things then hit prettier

or if you using `Javascript and its frameW n libs` then create file `.prettierrc.js` and then add those commends

```
module.exports = {
  trailingComma: "all",
  tabWidth: 4,
  singleQuote: "avoid",
};
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so here's my best try at an answer:

Prettier mainly supports these languages according to their page: `JavaScript · TypeScript · Flow · JSX · JSON CSS · SCSS · Less HTML · Vue · Angular GraphQL · Markdown · YAML` Make sure you're formatting one of those languages for best results.

If `Editor: Format On Save Mode` is set to `modifications` then you may not be able to go to an existing file and instantly format all of it.

If none of that helps I'm stumped and recommend looking at [Why Prettier does not format code in VSCODE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-prettier-does-not-format-code-in-vscode) if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Search for 'Prettier Path' in settings > select 'Edit in settings.json' and add the following config :

```
    {
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.fontSize": 12,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "[javascript]": {
    // "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true
  },
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "editor.columnSelection": false,
  "explorer.compactFolders": false,
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "prettier.prettierPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier"
}
```

Make sure prettier is installed at the given path : **"prettier.prettierPath": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier"**

You can make prettier the default also by uncommenting the code : **"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"**

It has my custom settings of visuals, so review those and then set, for beginners try pasting as-is!