# Update VSCOD Getting Error loading workspace folders

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode

After upgrade every time I open VS Code I get a `Error loading workspace folders` and Even All the extension were not working

```
go [-e -json -compiled=true -test=true -export=false -deps=true -find=false -- builtin ibm.com/cloudbroker/order/...]: exit status 1: build flag -mod=readonly only valid when using modules
: packages.Load error[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

go version go1.12.17 darwin/amd64
VsCode Version: 1.52.1
OS: Darwin x64 20.2.0

[image: Image Error Messgae]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

January 28 marked a major milestone in both the gopls and VS Code Go journeys, as gopls is now enabled by default in the Go extension for VS Code.

https://blog.golang.org/gopls-vscode-go

you need to disable the go.useLanguageServer flag in your settings.json

mine looks like this:

```
{
    "go.inferGopath": false,
    "go.toolsGopath": "C:\\Go",
    "go.useLanguageServer": false
}
```

Comment: Error loading workspace folders has been resolved but still I am getting error extension prettier Code formatter cannot format

Comment: this problem has been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-prettier-does-not-format-code-in-vscode

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this same issue for a while, thankfully after reading [VScode workspace thread](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md) and [gopals thread](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45015.), my problem has resolved

My Go Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

In VS code, open working project Repository alone.

Inside the project, run

> go mod init module_name

> go mod tidy

Hope, this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows and I had the same error and for me it was due to a mismatch between the path as it is on the disk vs the path on my powershell session from where I invoked vscode. Windows is not case sensitive when it comes to file paths but when I naviguate to my go project using powershell, I have to respect the case sensitivity for it to work.

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The full error I was getting was that the System32 was showing as system32. On the Terminal, just changed the path.

```bash
cd ..  
cd System32
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).