# VSCode Prettier not respecting Require Config option for Format on Save

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

### Description

I would like to configure the Visual Studio Code Prettier extension to automatically format on save, but **only** if a `.prettierrc` file exists in the project (what I understand as the "Prettier: Require Config" option).

### Issue

I have the following enabled in my VS Code settings:

- "Editor: Format On Save"
- "Prettier: Require Config"

Under the "Editor: Default Formatter" settings, the following behavior is happening depending on what I have selected:

- "None": Prettier does not format on save, regardless of the presence of a `.prettierrc` file
- "Prettier - Code formatter": Prettier always formates on save, regardless of the presence of a `.prettierrc` file.

[Similar to other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-does-prettier-not-format-code-in-vs-code), I seem to need Prettier set under "Editor: Default Formatter" in order for "Editor: Format on Save" to work at all. However, it seems the "Prettier: Require Config" setting effectively does nothing in any configuration I've tried. I have also tested with other supported configurations according to the [Prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html). Is there something I'm missing here?

### Software Versions

- Operating System: macOS 10.14.6
- Visual Studio Code: v1.56.0
- Prettier - Code formatter: v6.3.2

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where Prettier was formatting, despite the absence of the `.prettierrc` file.

When looking at the Prettier plugin logs in VSCode, it appears that Prettier will also look for the presence of a `.editorconfig` file, which I had in my project. Removing this solved the issue for me.

Comment: .editorconfig is created automaticallly when using `yarn init -2` and you're right: it overrides other configurations