# Prettier formatting not working on Mac with latest prettier extension version (v7.1.0)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I currently have prettier set as my default formatter in settings.json of vscode

The error received is:

> Extension 'Prettier - Code Formatter' cannot format './directory'

[image: vscode settings]

[image: error]

Comment: Have you set the language mode for the document?

Comment: Yes. Javascript is set. @evolutionxbox

Comment: Would this be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58669550/989920

Comment: @evolutionxbox Current version v7.1.0 of prettier ended up being the issue. I downgraded and it fixed my formatting.

Comment: Further update on this post. Prettier released v7.1.1 that fixed this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further update on this post. Prettier released v7.1.1 that fixed this bug. –