# Prettier on VS Code not working even after setting it as a default formatter

Tags: html

I did what everyone else said and put it as a default formatter but it still doesn't work...I even reinstalled VS Code but it doesn't work...

When I press Save (I enabled that option in settings) it console it says it formatted the code but actually it does nothing. What do I do because everyone is saying same stuff "PuT iT As A DeFaUlt FoRmAtTer"?

Comment: Did you already take a look at this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-does-prettier-not-format-code-in-vs-code

Comment: @kunsterD93 Yes I did...And nothing in there helped. After that I reinstalled VS Code and it still doesn't work...