# How to run prettier automatically in Nuxt.JS

Tags: nuxt.js, prettier, nodemon, prettify

Using Nuxt.JS, while on development with `npm run dev`, I want to trigger the command `npm run prettier` automatically when saving, to keep the code clean.

In any other project, I would achieve this with Nodemon with the following *nodemon.json*:

```js
{
  "events": {
    "restart": "npm run prettify"
  }
}
```

However Nuxt.JS doesn't seem to use Nodemon and/or it does not expose any "on change" event either.

#### How can I run a custom script when Nuxt.JS reloads?

Note: Looking for a solution **not** dependent on VSCode.

Comment: I do recommend this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585

Comment: That approach is good @kissu and I use it often on offline projects. However the code is edited online, through a web editor. So I am looking for a solution not dependent on VSCode.

Comment: The only remaining thing is to launch ESlint in any kind of code editor/IDE or run an ESlint service in the background to have it working.