# when i save my .js file the format will automatically change i have already install prettier it working on .jsx but not working on .js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

My VS code setting will automatically change i do not know what happen with my vs code i'm trying to solve this issue for 3 hours but still not able resolve this issue anybody can know this please let me know thanks in advance.

this is my vs code snippet of js file:
[image: this is my vs code snippet of js file]

this is my vs code json file formatting setting:
[image: this is my vs code json file formatting setting]

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-does-prettier-not-format-code-in-vs-code - check all of the answers as there are quite a few...

Comment: i try it but it's not working still @jonhendrix