# Prettier not formatting LESS files

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I suddenly have a problem where `prettier` can't format `.less` files.

I get this error message `Extension 'Prettier - Code formatter' is configured but it cannot format 'Less' files.`

I was working just normally until the other day. I've tried some things but haven't managed to find a fix for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Prettier not format code in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586965/why-does-prettier-not-format-code-in-vs-code)

Comment: I have this problem as well, but I get no error message. If I manually run "Format document with..." and choose Prettier, it works fine. Less files are selected under the settings auto-format options, and all other files format on save.