# How to solve a formating conflicts between VS Code auto-format(alt+shift+F) and VueJs default formating(npm run lint) rules?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I just initialized a VueJs Project:

```
npm init vue@3 .
Need to install the following packages:
  create-vue@3.3.2
Ok to proceed? (y) y

Vue.js - The Progressive JavaScript Framework

√ Package name: ... no-interrupts
√ Add TypeScript? ... Yes
√ Add JSX Support? ... Yes
√ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? ... Yes
√ Add Pinia for state management? ... Yes
√ Add Vitest for Unit Testing? ... No 
√ Add Cypress for both Unit and End-to-End testing? ... No 
√ Add ESLint for code quality? ... Yes
√ Add Prettier for code formatting? ... Yes
```

But now when I do format my code(alt+shift+f), prettier is underlining some things. If I run `npm run lint`, things go back to normal.

for example, alt-shift-F seems to try to keep the first property of html element on the first line:

```
<img alt="Vue logo"
     class="logo"
     src="@/assets/logo.svg"
     width="125"
     height="125" />
```

Where npm run lint have a dedicated line for each attribute:

```
<img
  alt="Vue logo"
  class="logo"
  src="@/assets/logo.svg"
  width="125"
  height="125"
/>
```

It's especially an issue because the file is formated on save.

I've not a strong preference, but if possible I would like to keep the one proposed by `npm run lint`.

my `eslintrc.cjs` contains the following:

```
/* eslint-env node */
require("@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution");

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript/recommended",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
  },
};
```

What should I do to have the `alt-shift-f` command formating properly my code?

Comment: Give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585

Comment: @kissu Any idea what would be the affected property in the config file? Mine is 9181 line long, so not sure what to look for? Also, Since I dev for other stacks, how to make those change persists only in this project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your default formatter in VS Code. Here is how to do it:

1. Install the [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) extension
2. Go to settings and search for "Default formatter"
3. Select ESLint

VS Code then automatically reads your ESLint configuration from your project and formats the code accordingly

Comment: eslint is already installed. I tried to set the "default formatter" for the workspace to be eslint, but it doesn't seems to improve anything