# How do I fix a "Vue packages version mismatch" error on Vue js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

When I run npm run dev on my nuxt js, I get the following error:

```
 FATAL                                                                                                                                                          14:16:02  

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@3.2.40
- vue-server-renderer@2.7.12

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.



  Vue packages version mismatch:

  - vue@3.2.40
  - vue-server-renderer@2.7.12

  This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\vue-server-renderer\index.js:8:9)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\@nuxt\vue-renderer\dist\vue-renderer.js:20:27)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
```

i try to resolve it by delete node modules and npm install, but it seems still not resolve my problem yet,any help on that, its been a while since i try to google it but still not giving me any answer on my problem,this happened when i install github co pilot
here is my package.json looks like

```json
{
  "name": "cashier",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.2.2",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "nuxt": "^2.13.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.40",
    "vue-google-charts": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.12",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.5",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to install `@vue/server-renderer` instead of `vue-server-renderer` ... please note however that `vuetify 2.x` is NOT compatible with vue3 - so you'll need to address that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuxt2 and Vue3 are not compatible together, one will use a package version which is incompatible with the other.

And anyway, Nuxt2 is only for a Vue2 usage. If you want to use Vue3, you need to use Nuxt3.

But if you use Nuxt (2 or 3), you don't need to install Vue because it's already baked-in into Nuxt.

It's important that you check that the packages you're using are compatible with their version.

Reinstalling the packages will not fix anything for the simple reason that your `package.json` is still wrong (some package versions are not compatible with others) waiting for a fix: choosing versions that work all together.

Also, you probably can even remove `vue-server-renderer` IMO since it is probably a dependency of another package.

PS: Github co-pilot is not related. Dotenv doesn't need to be installed because it's already baked-in into Nuxt. And you should probably not install Vuetify and the module of the same name at the same time. You also have `eslint-config-prettier` while not using ESlint at all apparently.

You can use this answer to configure ESlint + Prettier properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585

Comment: thanks a lot, but the most safest way for me just rollback to last version from github, i cannot resolve it as it getting more complicated after i remove some of the dependencies, but thanks a lot for ur answer, helping get through new project later on @kissu

Comment: @JansenStanlie yeah depends on what you already have as of right now. You may need to remove a few things out.