# Eslint doesn't fix the errors with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, eslint

First I created vue project.

```
npm init vue@latest
```

The settings are as follows.
[image]

Then I added rules to the .eslintrc.cjs.

```
/* eslint-env node */
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution')

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-typescript',
    '@vue/eslint-config-prettier'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest'
  },
  rules: {
    indent: ["error", 4],
    "vue/html-indent": ["error", 4],
  },
}
```

Finally I ran the program.

```
cd test
npm install
npm run lint
```

But I got the error.

```
✖ 209 problems (142 errors, 67 warnings)
  142 errors and 67 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

The setting of "scripts" in the package.json is as follows.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore"
  },
```

How can I fix the errors automatically?

Comment: Where do you have the error, in your code editor or console? That setup works perfectly fine on my side.

Comment: I got this error in the console (terminal)

Comment: I can replicate indeed, updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you.
After adding `{ "tabWidth": 4 }` to the `.prettierrc.json`, the number of errors decreased.

Comment: Yep, the hardest part is still to come hehe: the conflicts.

Comment: if you want to fix the errors automatically on save in VS Code you need to add "editor.codeActionsOnSave": ["source.fixAll.eslint"] in your settings.json

Comment: @c.m. it doesn't really fix the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: this is really the [4 spaces rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/indent#options) that is troublesome here.

I found out that restarting the ESlint server + ESlint'ing the file from VScode helps solving most of the **errors** (that could probably not be done) directly into the CLI.
But then, there are some conflicts regarding ESlint and Prettier.
Not sure exactly of the conflict here, even with a [`{ "tabWidth": 4 }`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#tab-width) in `.prettierrc.json`.

[image]

---

I recommend that you also add this to your settings (type `>Preferences: Open user settings (JSON)` in your command palette)

```json
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Dark", // example of some of your own configuration

  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
  },
  "eslint.options": {
    "extensions": [
      ".html",
      ".js",
      ".vue",
      ".jsx",
    ]
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact",
    "html",
    "vue",
  ],
}
```

Then type in `>ESlint: Restart ESLint Server` in palette too.

Oh, and don't forget to actually install the [ESlint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) and disable the Prettier one.

Here is one detailed answer on how to [configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585). It was done for Nuxt but still relatable in this case IMO.