# Vue project how to close eslint validate?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

In my vue.config.js file, I set

```
module.exports = {
    lintOnSave: false
}
```

but it doesn`t work.

Vue project how to close eslint validate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make a fully functional ESlint + Prettier configuration and have it saved in your VScode editor (or any other one able to properly run an ESlint configuration): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585

Tell me if you have any more issues regarding the configuration.