# Getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit')"NUXT

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store, state-management

I am new to Vue and stuck. I am trying to send user input data from a form into a vuex store. From that vuex store, an action will be called (fetching from API) and I would like that data back into my app and components.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>APP NAME</h1>
    <form action="submit" @submit.prevent="sendCityName()">
      <label for="query"></label>
      <input 
      type="text"
      id="query"
      v-model="cityName"
    >
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <h3>{{ lat }}</h3>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cityName: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    coordinates () {
      return this.$store.state.lat
    }

  },
  methods: {
    sendCityName() {
      this.$store.commit('fetchCity', this.cityName)
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is my index.vue and getting the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit')"

here is my store.js. I want to use the lat and lon across my app.

```js
export const state = () => ({
    lat: '',
    lon: ''
  })
  
export const mutations = {
    SET_LAT(state, payload){
      state.lat = payload
    },
    SET_LON(state, payload){
      state.lon = payload
    }
  }
  
export const actions = {
    async fetchCity({ commit }, cityName) {
      // make request
      axios.get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct`, {
          params: {
            appid: "xxxxxxx",
            q: cityName,
          }
        }).then((response) => {
            commit('SET_LAT', response.data[0].lat);
            commit('SET_LON', response.data[0].lng);
        }); 
    },
  };
```

When I button submit I get the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit')"

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong in that case, seems to be okay so far. What do you have if you `console.log` `this.$store`? Maybe give a try to [`mapMutations`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components). Which version of Vuex and Nuxt are you using?

Comment: I mean, since you're doing an async call you should be using [`mapActions`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components) anyway. Commits are used only for sync operations. Or `await this.$store.dispatch` if you want to directly target the store.

Comment: @kissu Vue 2 and Nuxt 2. With dispatch I get the same errors.Dispatch is the correct way to call it my bad. But I still get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dispatch')"

Comment: Do you have a public github repo by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Here is [my working repo](https://github.com/kissu/Vuex-Practice) with the fixes mentioned below.

---

There are 3 things in your code:

- remove `vuex` from `package.json` and run `yarn` again, that one is already baked into Nuxt as stated in the [official documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#activate-the-store), those are the only steps needed
- all the files inside of `store` will be [namespaced by default](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#modules) for you, since you do have `store/store.js`, the proper syntax will be

```js
async sendCityName() {
  await this.$store.dispatch('store/fetchCity', this.cityName) //  store prefix
}
```

- since you do use the axios module, you should have the following in your action (using the `async/await` syntax since it's more modern and preferable)

```js
async fetchCity({ commit }, cityName) {
  const response = await this.$axios.get(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct`, {
    params: {
      appid: "3d91ba5b3c11d13158a2726aab902a0b",
      q: cityName,
    }
  })
  commit('SET_LAT', response.data[0].lat)
  commit('SET_LON', response.data[0].lng)
}
```

---

Looking at the browser's console, you also have some errors to fix.

[image]

I can also recommend [an ESlint + Prettier configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585) so that you keep your code error-proof + properly formatted at all times.

Comment: @coolflow90 I've updated my answer with a working GitHub repo, mainly following all the steps that I've described. Didn't fix the `not defined on the instance` because it was not part of the question,

Comment: Cool, I will take a look at this and study!! Appreciate the effort

Comment: i am still getting the dispatch error however lol but i will try some other stuff out

Comment: @coolflow90 not with my repo. You're missing one of the steps I've mentioned above. Please give it another read.