# How to make Prettier ignore formatting code in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm new to Vue.js. I working on a Vue project and I'm having a problem with Prettier. I use Vue Language Features (Volar). I don't know if it's the problem. I use `// prettier-ignore` to make Prettier ignore the code line but it doesn't work.

**Code snippet:**

```
<script setup>
import { computed, onMounted } from "vue";
import store from "../store";
import axiosClient from "../axiosClient";

const meals = computed(() => store.state.meals);

// prettier-ignore
const letters = [
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "D",
  "E",
  "F",
  "G",
  "H",
  "I",
  "J",
  "K",
  "L",
  "M",
  "N",
  "O",
  "P",
  "Q",
  "R",
  "S",
  "T",
  "U",
  "V",
  "W",
  "X",
  "Y",
  "Z",
];
onMounted(() => {
  axiosClient.get("list.php?i=list");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on your configuration tbh, I tend to use Prettier through ESlint as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585).

If you still want to stick to Prettier as an extension in your VScode editor, then you should probably need to dive into some settings (check the link above, still relevant config settings there).

I also know that Volar may impact the whole thing too, hence you have 3 culprits to check on:

- ESlint
- Prettier
- Volar
- Vetur (if still in the project)
- Some other formatters/extensions

I recommend that you choose the one you wish to use (ESlint is the most universal if working with other people), and disable one by one to see who impacts what (check your `settings.json` file).
Do not forget to reload your editor from time to time to be sure to refresh the whole lint/extension server, can be finicky sometimes.

---

[image]
Checking your `problems view` can also be helpful to try to figure out what is impacting what (yeah, it's quite some configuration to have everything working well together).

---

This one may also be a decent read overall: https://antfu.me/posts/why-not-prettier