# How to change visual studio code settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to changes visual studio code settings.json but it is not working. I have updated this in C:\Users\Userid\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json but not working. How to edit settings.json file in vs code?

```json
{
    "css.experimental.customData": ["./css.json"],
    "json.schemas": [ 
        {
            "fileMatch": ["/css.json"],
            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/master/docs/customData.schema.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VSCode's [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) are split into 2 categories: User and Workspace.

### User settings

> Settings that apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open.

You can edit these settings by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
It should open to the User Settings tab. If it doesn't, click the User Settings tab to edit user settings. Note that these settings will affect all projects that you open using VSCode.

[image: VSCode settings pane with User Settings tab open]
*VSCode settings pane with User Settings tab open*

### Editing JSON schemas

The VSCode settings page does not allow direct editing of JSON Schemas.
To edit JSON schema settings:

1. Search JSON schemas in the VSCode settings page
2. Click "edit in settings.json"
3. Edit settings
4. Done!

[image: Edit json schema]
*JSON schema setting in VSCode*

Alternatively;

[image: another method to find setting.json]

### Workspace settings

> Settings stored inside your workspace and only apply when the workspace is opened.
> Workspace settings override user settings.

To edit workspace settings, follow steps for user settings, except click the Workspace Settings tab instead. Note that workspace settings will override user settings

### `css.experimental.customData`

You should put your css.json file in .vscode.

`projectRoot/.vscode/css.json`

```js
{
  "version": 1,
  "pseudoElements": [
    { "name": "::bar", "description": "Foo pseudo elements" }
  ]
}
```

`projectRoot/.vscode/settings.json`

```js
{
  "css.experimental.customData": ["./.vscode/css.json"],
  "json.schemas": [{
    {
      "fileMatch": ["css.json"],
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/master/docs/customData.schema.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: a [reload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002990/11168593) is required to apply changes after editing css.json.

You can also apply the above instructions for html.json

Comment: Thanks For your reply..How can i call css.json file form workspace?

Comment: "css.experimental.customData": ["./css.json"]..where i want to put this css.json file?

Comment: @cinnan I have added an edit to answer your question

Comment: Can i use this??? https://github.com/octref/simple-customdata/blob/master/.vscode/settings.json

Comment: JRO: I am waiting for your reply

Comment: Let me try it out and see if it works, I'll get back to you in a while

Comment: Can you try from your side and send me your setting,json file and html.json file code

Comment: and location also

Comment: Did you reload VSCode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190771/discussion-between-jro-and-cinnan).

Answer (score 2):

Add a folder called ".vscode" in your project and a settings.json in there. Tho keep in mind those settings are project specific

Comment: Thanks for your reply....Project specific working fine. But i want to set globaly

Comment: Try opening your command window with Ctrl+Shift+P and executing "Open Settings (JSON)"