# How to reload Python package after pip install in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I wonder how to reload Python package after `pip install` in Visual Studio Code?

1. `pip install package-A`
2. `pip list`
3. `package-A` does **not exist**
4. Restart 'Visual Studio Code'

Is the only way to restart?

Comment: does `Developer: Reload Window` solve the problem? Maybe Python language server caches the current available modules.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best answer I've found is to use `Developer: Reload Window` in the [*command palette*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) like *@rioV8* suggested. You can either use the command palette or you can change the key mappings as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002990/13342296).

There's already a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> *key mapping* for reloading the window, but it's got a 'when' condition attached to it so I changed that to true. I also had to delete *key mappings* for other extensions so there was no overlap.

Comment: this doesn't always work for me

Comment: Did you delete all the other actions tied to Ctrl + R?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and choose "Developer: Reload with extentions disabled"

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, use `command + shift + p` and then choose "Developer: Reload Window". It is helpful to bind this to `command + r`. For Windows users, replace `command` with `CTRL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the `Refresh Explorer` (The reload button) right next to the directory/workspace that you opened up in the File Explorer.

You might have to hover for a while next to the workspace/directory name on the file explorer once it's expanded to have it in view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mean `upgrade` or `re-install` ?

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>
```

OR

```
pip install -I <package>
pip install --ignore-installed <package>
```

Try these commands

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure this is a vscode issue? What happens when you run pip install from a normal command prompt? I suspect you will have the same issue, if that proves true, I would entirely uninstall python and re-install python, then install/upgrade pip to latest.

`python -m pip install –upgrade pip`