# VS2019/TypeScript 3.9.5/Intellisence Failure

Tags: typescript, intellisense, tsconfig

I'm experiencing an issue in where modifying tsconfig.json files within my Visual Studio 2019 IDE causes Intellisense to malfuntion.

In my case, my tsconfig.json is at the base of my project which extends a file called base.json (the base config for the entire project).  Its target=ES6 and its module=ESNEXT.  When I modify this file, it there is immediate affect.  In addition, Intellisense sometimes fails from this point forward.  What I've observed is that any files, that where open before the change, remain to have Intellisense, but any other files opened have no intellisence bar or type assistance.  Lastly, the Intellisense output window show no error messages and the IDE also gives no indication of an issue.

The only work around is to close VS and open the project again, which is a big pain.

Comment: Could you post your `tsconfig.json` file and if possible reproduce this issue in a short amount of code?

Comment: BTW, I'm using VS 16.6.2 with TypeScript Tools v16.0.62006.03190 and my project is a .njsproj type.  I'm also using TypeScript v3.9.5 in my packae.json.

Comment: 'yeerk',

Absolutely, but I don't see a "Share Files" option on Stackoverflow.  Please advise on how I go about sharing my files.

Comment: "The only work around is to close VS and open the project again, which is a big pain." You can use the "Reload window" command https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002990/1276128. Not ideal, but faster and less painful.

Comment: It isn't super easy to add a large amount of code, but you can post code blocks (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Sometimes you can create a reproducible sample in a 3rd party site (such as codesandbox.io), but you should always post the crux of the problem on StackOverflow, otherwise future users may not have access to the 3rd party site (which may not exists a few years down the road when other users have the same question).

Comment: 'yeerk',

I've shared my files [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmQjdkuQlBVxhqRdIXn-s2fupJWs-A?e=bL0NMe).

Comment: Marko Gresak,

There is no "Reload Window" in Visual Studio Professional (which is what I'm using), but rather in Visual Studio Code.