# How to restart VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to entirely restart VSCode? I do *not* mean [reloading a single window.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002852/how-to-restart-vscode-after-editing-extensions-config)

VSCode lets you restart when an update is installed via the self updater, but I can't see a way to access this functionality when there isn't an update.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3592 6 years old feature request

Comment: Damn, well it should be fairly easy to implement so I will have a go at some point.

Comment: ...Yes. Just close all your VS Code windows and then reopen them. What about that approach doesn't work for you? I'm assuming you already thought of that. But nothing in your question post clarifies why that's not acceptable. Elaborate on your requirements.

Comment: I have a lot of windows so that is extremely tedious. I would have thought that is pretty obvious to be honest, otherwise why would I be asking this question in the first place? Come on.

Comment: Unfortunately I looked through the code and the "Restart to update" command is really a "Restart *and* update" command. It's all done as part of Electron's autoupdater, so I don't think it is trivial to add a "restart" command. Well I mean it is trivial but it would be a "restart and update if there is an update pending" command which may be hard to explain to users.