# Python3 on RPi4 "import picamera2" command works in Thonny but fails in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, camera

I'm running a Python3 program to record a small video on a Raspberry Pi 4B:

`   import time

```
from picamera2 import Picamera2
from picamera2.encoders import H264Encoder

picam2 = Picamera2()
video_config = picam2.create_video_configuration()
picam2.configure(video_config)

encoder = H264Encoder(10000000)
picam2.start_recording(encoder,'/home/pi/test.h264')
 time.sleep(10)
picam2.stop_recording()`
```

When I run this program in VS_Code I receive an error message "no module named picamera2".  When I run the same program in Thonny it records a video.  Executing import picamera2 in the terminal works also.  I like working in VS_Code.  Does anyone have an idea why it is reporting an error?  Thanks, Jim.

Comment: Have you tried [reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002990/11286032) your vscode window?

Comment: Do they all use the same Python installation and there’s no virtual environments in play? VS Code should show a selection of Python version, check that it’s the correct one if you happen to have multiple

Answer (score 1):

If you are pressing the run button on the vscode then the appropriate python interpreter should be pointed. if you are running in terminal u know for which interpreter u have installed all the libraries.

To get this solved u just have to choose the right interpreter in the vs code:

you can follow the below step if u have created a venv and using it:

**step 1:** click on the python version displayed on the right botton corner of your vscode.

**step2:** select the enter interpreter path if you want to specify manual alternate path of the python interpreter if you are not using venv.

[image: interpreter]

**step2 :** alternative if you are using a venv click as shown below , vs code automatically picks the right version for you.

[image: venv selection]